# Higher res images are being zoomed in and cropped in ImageView

Tags: android

I have an image in an ImageView. The ImageView is 40x40 but the actual source image is 80x80 for higher res devices. So, the image was exported at 2x.

However, the image in the ImageView is being zoomed-in on and cropped. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Here is my code:

```
<ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/attachment_button"
                    android:layout_width="40dp"
                    android:layout_height="40dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
                    android:src="@drawable/button_mobile_attachment" />
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried with `scaleType="centerInside"`? also `adjustViewBounds` seems to be unnecessary set, as you have fixed dimens anyway

Comment: "centerInside" did not work. It's making the icon really small.

Comment: I fixed the issue by using a Figma plugin to export the image at the various Android drawable folder sizes. Seems to have fixed the issue.